# Most efficient way of animating hundreds of gameobjects with blender shape keys

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, coding-efficiency

I have my trees edited by shape keys in blender, now I want to trigger this wind animation in unity. I used animator and controller for this, but now I found out that there are blendshapes and I could use loop to change blendshape key value. There will be more than hundreds of trees, and i think to start courotine for each tree is not efficient, nor update this value each frame. It should run endlessly, of course I will animate only visible trees, but still dont know most efficient way.

Comment: Put them in a List/array then use **one** coroutine with a `for` loop to iterate over each one and animate them..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else can give a more technical answer for how you can do it (as you are asking), but the more practical answer is that you wouldn't. Find some way to cheat it. Use 2D sprites that look good enough, like even most AAA games do/did. Or at least make sure you've only got a few trees visible at a time. If they're close enough to really notice, then you could use 3D for just the close models with 2D stuff in the back, etc. 
Or some other your-game-specific way you can think of to cheat the art.

Comment: I use faceted low poly trees, so sprites are not solution for me. I think blendshapes are easiest way of simulate wind. Question is how to keep so many animations running smoothly.

Comment: Thats the challenge, how to work sprites into your setup. Ideal its a mixture of both :)